# Working for the EU

Tags: eu-citizens, working, europe

I'd like to ask the following and I truly hope to receive an answer that somehow fulfills the present enquiry.

Workers in the EU institutions and varying sub-branches are under a hierarchy or level system, and after a search the lowest level is labeled as AST.

I have read in Italian that in order to work in this position a selection should be passed and that only a high school degree in sufficient, I did not see any requirement of university/college degree as a qualification requirement.

Now, is it true or not? Can someone enlighten me any further?

Comment: Some clues here maybe : https://epso.europa.eu/job-opportunities_en

Answer (score 1):

For AST positions, [it's possible to qualify through relevant professional experience](https://epso.europa.eu/career-profiles/support-staff_en) even if you don't have a post-secondary education. This is just a baseline to be eligible to take part. The recruitment process is very competitive, certainly for AD positions.